# Can the value of the key-value pair returned by aggregate operations in MongoDB be extracted?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation

This is a code that attempts to get the highest brand average price.

```
var x = db.inventory.aggregate([
{$match:{'Origin':'USA'}},
{$group:{_id:'$Brand', top_avgprice:{$avg:'$Price'}}},
{$project: {_id:0,top_avgprice:1}},
{$sort: {top_avgprice:-1}},
{$limit:1}
])
```

Printing x returns a key-value pair, e.g. *top_avgprice: 10,000*

But when I try to access the value by doing the code below, it returns nothing.

```
x.top_avgprice
```

How do I return that 10,000 alone? I'll need this integer value later for another expression.

Comment: aggregate() method will always result in array, you can try `x[0].top_avgprice`

Answer (score 0):

when you do aggregate it returns data with cursor so you need to iterate through it to access data like below:

```
var x = db.inventory.aggregate([
{$match:{'Origin':'USA'}},
{$group:{_id:'$Brand', top_avgprice:{$avg:'$Price'}}},
{$project: {_id:0,top_avgprice:1}},
{$sort: {top_avgprice:-1}},
{$limit:1}
]).toArray();

x.forEach(function(e) {
    print('e.top_avgprice: ', e.top_avgprice);

});
```